# Accessing property of a union type in Angular template

Tags: angular, templates

I have an union type item like the following:

```
export interface A {
  a: number
}

export interface B {
  b: string
}

export type MyUnionType = A | B;
```

I'd like to check in the template if an object of type MyUnionType is of type A or B based on the presence of the property a or b.

I expected something like this should work:

```
<div *ngIf="'a' in item">
  {{item.a}}
</div>
```

[Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngifin)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use this way:

In ts:

```
getTypeA(item: A | B): A { 
  return (item as A);
}

getTypeB(item: A | B): B { 
  return (item as B);
}
```

in html:

```
<div>{{ getTypeA(item).a }}</div>
<div>{{ getTypeB(item).b }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above approach will not work.
When you define combined type like MyUnionType combining two or more types the resulting type expects all the properties present in child types also there should be one common property that exists in both of them.

```
 export interface A {
  a: number;
  c: string;
}

export interface B {
  b: string;
  c: string;
}

export type MyUnionType = A | B;
```

Below snippet will work

```
    <div>
      {{item.c}}
    </div>
```

```
// But below snippet will not work. Since TypeScript does not know which of the three
// potential types a could be.
// Trying to access a property which isn't shared
// across all types will raise an error
    <div>
       {{item.a}}
   </div>
```

How to work with such types is very well documented here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html

Comment: Yes, but using the in operator the typescript can infer the type, so inside if('a' in item) the item is no longer of type A | B but it's only A (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types). I'd like to same feature also in angular template

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm under the same problem atm.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't a type predicate the best way to achieve this?
See typescript docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates).

```
function isOfTypeA(something: any): something is A {
    return (
      typeof something === 'object' &&
      something !== null &&
      'a' in something
    );
}
```

Then in the template you can do:

```
<div *ngIf="isOfTypeA(item)">
    {{item.a}}
</div>
```

And the compiler wont complain as it knows you have determined that it is indeed of type A.